# Chromium in jest-playwright returns wrong date format

Tags: typescript, jestjs, chromium, playwright

I want to use a correct date format in my jest-playwright tests.

I am using:

```js
    const currentdate = new Date().toLocaleDateString("de-DE", {
        day: "2-digit",
        month: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
    });
    console.log(currentdate);
```

This code snippet returns the correct format e.g. `17.09.2021`in my firefox and my chrome browser. But in playwright with chromium it returns `2021-09-17`. Is this a bug or how can I get the correct german date format in my playwright tests?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, for me it's working. Could you file an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/new/choose) if you still encounter it?

Comment: hi, same pb here, did you figure it out?

Comment: @kevinob Yes, it was the page reload, so the date wasn't mocked anymore. I have to mock it on the correct page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with a page reload.

I mocked it on the wrong page, and after I went to another URL the date was overwritten.